# Wordpress How to set ACF once to be displayed on all pages

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a `custom-field` with type of Repeater which I want to be displayed in the header and footer through all the pages. In the backend, I set the `Show this field group if` to

```
- Post type is equal to page
- Post type is not equal to page
```

This gives me two problems:

1) The custom field appears on each `Page` in the backend

2) I have to add the same content on each page to make them appear in the Header and Footer

So, my wish-scenario is that I only have to add the content once, for example the Frontpage and that it then gets displayed in the header and footer on all pages. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access custom fields from another page by specifying the page ID in the ACF call.

IE:

```
<?php the_field('field_name', 123); ?>
```

So you would just enter the content on one page and then use the above code to display that content on any other page(just replace `123` with the page ID you want to pull the content from).

[Read more about it here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-another-post/).

Alternatively, you could use an [ACF Options Page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/) to accomplish this.

Comment: I too would suggest ACF Options Page. That's exactly what you're after.